# how to solve first kind freholm integral equation .

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, numerical-methods, integral-equations

I want to solve
$$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\ln\left(\frac{1}{|x-y|}\right)dx=1$$
Where f(x) is unknown function.
i want to solve these equation and how to convert it to matrix form.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the site. You are encouraged to learn MathJax / LaTeX typesetting as well as show any own attempts you've made at solving the problem. Both of those will increase the chances of getting constructive feedback.

Comment: I tried helping you with the typesetting this time, please let me know if I got anything wrong.

Comment: This is the Carleman's equation. You will find a solution at [EqWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ie/ie0312.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, applying the result from [EqWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ie/ie0312.pdf),$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi\ln 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: 1- how can i use that for approximation.and i need to treat singularity of the kernel.

Comment: Well, this is the solution to the integral equation. I did not notice you were looking for a numerical solution, sorry. It may however help you verify your calculation...

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts... Paul Enta